# Valid RSS 2.0 Using Rome

Tags: java, xml, rss, rome

Im using [rome 1.0](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home) to generate RSS for my java application.

In my java:

```
    SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedImpl();
    feed.setFeedType( "rss_2.0" );
    feed.setTitle( "My Site" );
    feed.setLink( "http://example.com" );
    feed.setDescription( "Test Site." );    

    List<SyndEntry> entries = new ArrayList<SyndEntry>();
    SyndEntry entry = null;
    SyndContent description = null;

    entry = new SyndEntryImpl();
    entry.setTitle( "Entry1" );
    entry.setLink( "http://example.com/entry1" );
    entry.setPublishedDate( new Date() );

    description = new SyndContentImpl();
    description.setType("text/html");
    description.setValue( "This is the content of entry 1." );
    entry.setDescription( description );

    entries.add( entry );
    feed.setEntries(entries);

    Writer writer = new FileWriter("/home/jr/Desktop/stream.xml");
    SyndFeedOutput output = new SyndFeedOutput();
    output.output(feed,writer);
    writer.close();
```

The generated RSS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link>http://example.com</link>
    <description>Test Site.</description>
    <item>
      <title>Entry1</title>
      <link>http://example.com/entry1</link>
      <description>This is the content of entry 1.</description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 09 Nov 2012 01:28:57 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid>http://example.com/entry1</guid>
      <dc:date>2012-11-09T01:28:57Z</dc:date>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

When RSS is validated [here](http://validator.w3.org/appc/), it has the following recommendations:

- An item should not include both pubDate and dc:date
- Missing atom:link with rel="self"

How to do the recommendation in rome library? Is the generated RSS ok?

Thanks.

Comment: Partially answered in [atom:link in RSS using Rome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112949/atomlink-in-rss-using-rome).

Comment: Just wanted to mention that @JoshC13's answer indeed works, but it should be applied to `SyndEntryImpl` instead of `SyndFeedImpl`, since the duplicated date is happening under the `<item>` element

Answer (score 2):

In your custom SyndFeed class, make sure that you name your Date variable differently from what's on the SyndFeed class (Ie: instead of 'publishedDate', use something like 'pubDate'. This seems to have solved the issue for me.

```
public class CustomSyndFeed extends SyndFeedImpl {

protected Date pubDate;

    @Override
    public Date getPublishedDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPublishedDate(final Date pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = new Date(pubDate.getTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Happy Coder!  I see you're new here, so just a heads-up.  We usually try to reserve answers for new techniques or approaches and use comments for small addendums like changing variable names since they don't represent an alternative approach.  I understand your plight since the reputation requirements put the comments section off-limits for now.  Perhaps stating your problem here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

So this is happening because the `SyndFeedImpl` uses the same field for the date and publishedDate fields (from the DC Module) :

```
@Override
public Date getPublishedDate() {
    return getDCModule().getDate();
}

@Override
public void setPublishedDate(final Date publishedDate) {
    getDCModule().setDate(publishedDate);
}
```

Since the `RSS093Generator` (used by the `RSS20Generator`) creates a pubDate element from the specified item, but also inherits from the DCModuleGenerator, you get both this:

```
final Date pubDate = item.getPubDate();
        if (pubDate != null) {
            eItem.addContent(generateSimpleElement("pubDate", DateParser.formatRFC822(pubDate, Locale.US)));
        }
```

and this:

```
final Date dcDate = dcModule.getDate();
if (dcDate != null) {
    for (final Date date : dcModule.getDates()) {
        element.addContent(generateSimpleElement("date", DateParser.formatW3CDateTime(date, Locale.US)));
    }
}
```

This interaction can be prevented by implementing a custom `SyndFeed` of your own.  In this case, all you need to do is create a class variable to store your pubDate so that the `DCModule` never gets a date set, and will therefore never generate your unwanted `dc:date` element.

I ran into the exact same problem and solved it by using this `SyndFeed` implementation:

```
public class CustomSyndFeed extends SyndFeedImpl {

    protected Date publishedDate;

    @Override
    public Date getPublishedDate() {
        return publishedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPublishedDate(final Date publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = new Date(publishedDate.getTime());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party, but no answer here works out of the box, so I figured I'd add mine.

As @Vitor points out in his comment, the correct way of doing this to extend `SyndEntryImpl` and use it as `SyndEntry entry = new CustomEntryImpl();`.

```
public class CustomEntryImpl extends SyndEntryImpl {

    protected Date pubDate;

    @Override
    public Date getPublishedDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPublishedDate(final Date pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = new Date(pubDate.getTime());
    }
}
```