# Atom:link in RSS using Rome

Tags: java, module, rss, atom-feed, rome

It is [recommended](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#namespace-elements-atom-link) to add  to RSS 2.0.

I am wondering if there is any Rome module available to add this tag? Like what they developed for content, media, [etc](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/MODULES/Home).

Comment: Does anyone know if this has been updated with Rome 1.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The blog post [Adding Atom links to an RSS feed generated by ROME](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2011/02/14/all-roads-lead-to-rome/) answers exactly that question:

> there is no build-in immediate support for Atom elements inside an RSS feed
>   ...
>   I’ve implemented an AtomContent class that holds a list of com.sun.syndication.feed.atom.Link but is easy extensible.

The code is published as https://github.com/michael-simons/java-syndication .

Comment: Here's also a working example, that is live at my JUGs website:
https://github.com/EuregJUG-Maas-Rhine/site/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/euregjug/site/web/IndexRssView.java Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a module, but you can use `Channel.getForeignMarkup()` if you want to add simple elements to your Channel.

```java
org.jdom2.Element atomLink = new Element("link", org.jdom2.Namespace.getNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"));
atomLink.setAttribute("href", "http://dallas.example.com/rss.xml");
atomLink.setAttribute("rel", "self");
atomLink.setAttribute("type", "application/rss+xml");

channel.getForeignMarkup().add(atomLink);
```

```
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="http://dallas.example.com/rss.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

Comment: After a lot of looking around and trying some solutions that involve creating a Rome module.  (none of which I had success with) I tried this little block of code and it worked.   Well, I should say it worked enough that the RSS Feed validator no longer returns an error