# How to make rss feed into the java webapp on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, widget, rss, rome

I have prepared the servlet according to https://rometools.github.io/rome/ROMEReleases/ROME0.4Beta/RomeV0.4Tutorials/RomeV0.4TutorialUsingRomeWithinAServletToCreateAndReturnAFeed.html example. However, the rss is not validated on https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi being created from scratch (and thus the feed not validated, for example, in Yandex widget policy), it misses the element in the channel tag.

There are several tips like [Atom:link in RSS using Rome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112949/atomlink-in-rss-using-rome) how to enable the atom:link, but they are based on rome.properties and it is impossible to use them on GAE - property file is not loaded to the webapp's classpath. 
So that is the easiest way to make atom:link to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was realized, that the missed element can be added to the xml right in the servlet, so additional Module class for Rome are not needed for this particular purpose:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    try {
        SyndFeed feed = getFeed(req, dataEntries, streamGauge);

        String feedType = req.getParameter(FEED_TYPE);
        feedType = (feedType != null) ? feedType : _defaultFeedType;
        feed.setFeedType(feedType);
        res.setContentType(MIME_TYPE);
        SyndFeedOutput output = new SyndFeedOutput();

        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        output.output(feed, writer);

        SAXBuilder db = null;
        Document doc = null;
        db = new SAXBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(writer.toString()));
        try {
            doc = db.build(is);
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Element root =
                doc.getRootElement();

        Element channel = root.getChild("channel");

        FeedServlet.AtomNSModule atomNSModule = (FeedServlet.AtomNSModule) module;
        root.addNamespaceDeclaration(ATOM_NS);

        Element atomLink = new Element("link", ATOM_NS);
        atomNSModule.setLink("http://volgalevel.appspot.com/feed");
        atomLink.setAttribute("href", atomNSModule.getLink());
        atomLink.setAttribute("rel", "self");
        atomLink.setAttribute("type", "application/rss+xml");

        channel.addContent(0, atomLink);
        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
        outputter.output(doc, res.getWriter());
    } catch (FeedException ex) {
        String msg = COULD_NOT_GENERATE_FEED_ERROR;
        log(msg, ex);
        res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, msg);
    }
}
```

note the imports:

```
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.Namespace;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.*;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

actually a working GAE Servlet for RSS can be reached there: https://github.com/Eljah/volgalevel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/appspot/FeedServlet.java

it also fixes duplicated pubDate problem